# Getting Zoom from google maps element using selenium

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, selenium, protractor

What I'm tying to accomplish:  I want to write a UI Test using protractor that will click a marker in an angular directive that uses Google Maps.

My first test will be to see if clicking the marker has changed the *zoom* value of the google maps.  I want to get value from element.getZoom() before and after a click and compare the two.

I open browser.get() up to the page containing my google maps directive.

Once the directive is loaded and I have the WebdriverWebElement that corresponds to my Google Maps container, **is it possible to reference the actual DOM element** so I can call DomElement.getZoom() in my protractor test?

or

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods and get the return value on a given WebElement by:

```
browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getZoom()', webelement);
```

Comment: use `getWebElement()` method while using `browser.executeScript()`. Example :`browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getZoom()', webelement.getWebElement());`

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) you should be able to use the webelement. I've never used Protractor before though, so I can't confirm